# Django: how select items that do not have referencies from other items?

Tags: django, orm

Assume, we have a model:

```py
class Critters(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Critters, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

In begin was some critters:

```
id  Name      Parent
==  ========  ========
 0  Critter1
 1  Critter2
 2  Critter3
```

And then, some critters made a children:

```
id  Name      Parent
==  ========  ======
 0  Critter1
 1  Critter2
 2  Critter3
 3  Child1         0
 4  Child2         1
```

I wand make a request for select **all parents without childrens** (i.e. no creatures with parents, and no parents with existing childrens):

```
id  Name      Parent
==  ========  ======
 2  Critter3
```

I think it can be done with `annotate` and `exact` django's directives, but i'm dubt in stick how exactly i can make this...

**UPDATE1**
Ofcourse, `critter` and `child` in field `Name` just for example, we can't filter table by `Name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think it can be done with annotate and exact django's directives.

It can be done even simpler. You can filter with:

```
Critters.objects.filter(parent=None, critters=None)
```

We thus filter on the reversed relation. This is a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and then check if that is `None`. It will thus make a query that looks like:

```
SELECT *
FROM critters
LEFT OUTER JOIN critters AS c ON c.parent_id = critters.id
WHERE parent_id IS NULL AND c.id IS NULL
```

Comment: I'm test your answer on real datatable and found that your answer is fully correct! But can you explain in more detail how `critters=None` do a reverse search?

Comment: @swasher: it will make a query as shown in the edited answer.